# Как исправить проблему в плагине jQuery Сhosen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Ребят, помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с плагином Сhosen последней версии. Решил переделать плагина под себя, в плане дизайна. Переделал, но есть небольшая проблема, которая мешает.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K07BXzSaWKagqXpXQFmmApSWooCRYix7 -решение.

Когда кликаешь по select открывается окно на всю страницу, после выбора нужного значения окно закрывается и значение выбрано, но если попробовать нажать вновь на тот же select, происходит авто выбор и окно закрывается. Решил проблему тем, что через css сделал задержку появления для блока с значениями, всё круто, но опять же. Как я понял из-за фокуса происходит так, что второй раз кликнув на этот элемент происходит резкое закрытие окна.

Как можно убрать этот фокус и избавиться от данной проблемы? Уже другой плагин пробовал Selecator 3, но там ещё хуже всё... Надежда на Вас)

UPDATE 31.5 -Вопрос решён, помогли на другом ресурсе. Ссылка ведёт уже к готовому решению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*chosen.jquery.js* 717 строка:

```
this.container.on('mousedown.chosen', (function(_this) {
```

заменить НА:

```
this.container.on('mouseup.chosen', (function(_this) {
```